# Why does VSCode not open in a winndows Dev container even if DOCKER_BUILDKIT is 0?

Tags: docker, vscode-extensions

This error:

```
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with fr
ontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to mount in-place: {bind
 C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\tf3u8e4ubnau1y7ah0xc6c3co [rbind ro]}: inva
lid windows mount type: 'bind'
```

and similar errors like it usually mean that [Docker Buildkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71686761/8981474) is active when it shouldn't be since [buildkit does not support building windows images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995122/8981474).

However, I deactivate DOCKER_BUILDKIT inside my [`.devcontainer.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_create-a-devcontainerjson-file) as prescribed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/environment-variables):

```
{ 

"image": "<image_url>:main", 

    "customizations": { 

        "vscode": { 

                "extensions": ["ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack", "webfreak.debug"] 

        } 

    }, 
    "containerEnv": {
        "DOCKER_BUILDKIT": "0"
    },
    "remoteEnv": {
        "DOCKER_BUILDKIT": "0"
    },

"shutdownAction": "stopContainer", 

"runArgs": ["-i", "--rm"] 

}
```

In addition, here is my docker desktop settings for windows:
[image]

Unfortunately, when I run the command "Dev Containers: Reopen in container" the error still pops up as above, I am unsure what change I made could have caused this, because I have used a similar .devcontainer.json file for a different project and they error never appeared.

Why does it have an issue with bind mouting when I have followed the correct format for a .devcontainer.json file?

Comment: I use Docker Buildkit all the time on Windows, so I'm not sure what you mean when you claim it's not supported.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that buildkit does not support building windows images.

Answer (score 0):

If one has Docker Desktop installed, you can switch between windows containers and Linux containers. Go to the docker desktop icon in the bottom menu bar and right click. Then select switch to Linux containers.  This should address your issue:

[image]

In my case my menu says "witch to Windows containers..." since I am currently using Linux containers.